# Making a sharepoint site (2007) read only

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am getting ready to perform a migration of SharePoint 2007 to 2010, and during the migration horus, i will want to prevent anyone form adding content anywhere, but yet I would like for people to read the content.  Is there a way to make the sharepoint 2007 site read only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are performing a database attach upgrade, you could set the databases to read-only through SQL Management Studio. When SharePoint databases are set to read-only, SharePoint will automatically security-trim all sites in those databases to only allow for viewing the content.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
   stsadm -o setsitelock -url http://server_name -lock noaccess
```

That will help you set the site collection to read-only

Comment: That command will actually stop ALL access to the site. To make it properly read-only, change the last parameter to `readonly` (i.e. `stsadm -o setsitelock -url http://server_name -lock readonly`)

Answer (score 4):

Its very simple:

Central Administration > Application Management > Site Collection Quotas and Locks. Then choose 'Read Only'.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is a way to do it in the UI or through stsadm, but there is a [readonly property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spsiteadministration.readonly.aspx) of the [SPSiteAdministration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spsiteadministration.aspx) object.

```
SPSiteAdministration siteAdmin = new SPSiteAdministration(siteUrl/guid);
siteAdmin.ReadOnly = true;
siteAdmin.Dispose();
```